# How to log with Serilog to Oracle using appsettings.json?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, asp.net-core, serilog, appsettings

I'm working on a project where I'm converting an application's database from MSSqlServer to Oracle. I'm using Serilog for the logging, and the Serilog.Sinks.Oracle project for further help.

This is the program.cs code for my MSSQLServer implementation:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

This is a snippet of the appsettings.json code also for the MSSQLServer implementation (the rest not shown is the implementation of custom columns):

```
{
"AllowedHosts": "*",
 "Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
   "Default": "Information",
   "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
   }
  },
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "MSSqlServer",
    "Args": {
      "connectionString": "connString",
      "schemaName": "dbo",
      "tableName": "TestLog5",
      "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
```

How would I go about recycling this code to change it to work with Oracle? The Serilog.Sinks.Oracle project gives instructions on how to implement it from program.cs, but I really need the configuring to come from appsettings.json.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code and configuration data as text inside code fences. Burying this information in linked images doesn't help other people searching for answers to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this possibility seems not to exist.
You can create an extension method like this :

```
public static LoggerConfiguration Oracle(this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration, string connectionString)
{
    var sink = new BatchLoggerConfiguration()
            .WithSettings(connectionString)
            .UseBurstBatch()
            .CreateSink();
    return loggerConfiguration.Sink(sink);
}
```

Arguments of your extension method have to correspond to json properties under Args property.
Name in json should correspond to your extension method name.

Sample configuration file :

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "<your assembly name>"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "..output-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": "10485760"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Oracle",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=xxxx"
        }
      }
```